# GtkCellRendererText: "editable-set" set to FALSE does not deactivate editability?

Tags: c, gtktreeview

If I use for example

```
g_object_set (renderer, "background", "red", "background-set", FALSE, NULL);
```

for a text renderer, the background color of a row inside a treeview is not set to red, as intended.

If I try something similar for the editability with

```
g_object_set (renderer, "editable", TRUE, "editable-set", FALSE, NULL);
```

the cell remains editable. I use a cell data function for each row, where I set "editable" to TRUE or FALSE for each cell and that works fine for me, but isn't "editable-set" set to FALSE supposed to deactivate the editability anyway, or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `"editable-set" == FALSE` tells the renderer to ignore the `"editable"` property and just use its own default, which is to be editable.

If you want to turn editable off, specify `"editable" == FALSE` and `"editable-set" == TRUE`.

Comment: Hm, if I set `"editable-set"` to FALSE, the renderer does not ignore the editable property in my case (inside the cell data function), simplified example `g_object_set (renderer, "editable", (column_number == 0 && strcmp (column_txt, "editable") == 0)), "editable-set", FALSE, NULL);`

Comment: Or, to say it differently, column 0 (the first column) is still editable if its text is "editable", if the text differs, it is not editable, so the `editable` property is not ignored.

Comment: Usually in API patterns like this one, setting `"editable"` also automatically sets `"editable-set"` to `TRUE`. My guess is that `g_object_set` does not guarantee the order in which the properties are set. I can't really know what's going on without seeing more of the code.